# Adding resource in code and using it as StaticResource

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

For some reason I am unable to bind to ViewModel properties within DataTemplates on some controls. The result of the binding itself is unpredictable, sometimes it work, sometimes it doesn't. For this reason I am thinking of exposing the ViewModel in some other way besides setting it as DataContext.

First thought was to add ViewModel to Resources collection. I am using TabControls for UI, so whenever a view needs to be displayed, it is done through Data templates.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SomeViewModel}">
    <vw:SomeView />
</DataTemplate>
```

In this situation the view is instantiated automatically, and its DataContext is set to ViewModel set in template. Is there a way I can make this ViewModel available to View's Resources (ex with key=viewModel), so that I can use it like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" />
```

I have tried adding it in code, in the Loaded event for the View:

```
this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
{
    this.Resources.Add("viewModel", this.DataContext);
};
```

Above code is executed before the error pops up that says static resource is not found at run-time, so the resource was added to collection.

Any ideas what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define ViewModel as a resource in XAML like that:

```
<vm:SomeViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
```

If you want to Bind to DataContext in a DataTemplate you can use the following:

`{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=uc}`

assuming that your window/usercontrol name is x:Name="uc" , or as @stukselbax wrote:

```
{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=[UserControl|Window]}}
```

Comment: That would create a new instance of SomeViewModel. Also, it is assuming SomeViewModel doesn't have parameterized constructor. Nevertheless, I want to use already created SomeViewModel, that is set to View's DataContext, and not to create a new one.

Comment: So then, why do you need the ViewModel as a resource? Couldn't you simply Bind to a property named ViewModel or DataContext (ViewModel)?

Comment: There is no property called ViewModel. I can bind to SomeViewModel through DataContext property - normally. However, imagine situation where you have a Grid control, containing Columns collection, and you are defining a Column and its CellEditTemplate. Trying to bind withing this template to DataContext will fail.

Comment: it will not, you can bind to your Window's, UserControl's DataContext like that: {Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=uc} assuming that your window/usercontrol name is x:Name="uc"

Comment: @PiotrPtak Or using relative source, somthing like: {Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=[UserControl|Window]}}

Comment: No, both cannot work, I have tested it for hours and results are unpredictble. Most of time time ElementName cannot be used within DataTemplate, while RelativeSource sometimes work, sometimes doesn't.

Comment: @Goran, so it works but as you wrote "unpredictable". Therefore, I assume that you have an error somewhere else in the application but cannot identify the source of the problem. The case might be that your DataContext is changing periodically or ViewModel is somehow unnecessary instantiated more than once. It would be nice if you could provide more code.

Comment: No, I can isolate the problem with binding a grid to a list of items. Of there are ten rows in a grid, I can (but not necesserily) receive error for only two rows (rows, not columns) that binding didn't work. the error is regular binding error: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor...

Comment: As for the code, if you insist on providing it, I can do so, but its quite basic, and I am not sure what kind of code can throw binding exception on 3 rows and not throw on 7 rows for example, since the binding is the same for all rows. I have another question, similar to this, where  I have asked the question similar to this, and I am going to add code there.

Comment: Please post the XAML code for which the binding exception is raised and other applicables for this issue

Comment: I do not want to relate this question to this error, because I already have a question specific to this error. This question is how to add a resource in code, and access it in xaml. If you think you can help me with solving the issue with binding, you can answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784764/problems-with-binding-to-viewmodel-properties-from-data-templates. I have posted xaml code there just now that is throwing an exception.

Comment: @Goran, I just think that adding ViewModel as a resource in code behind is not a good option (and good habit) because you already have that ViewModel in a DataContext. You should just simply Bind that DataContext. You wrote that it works but "unpredictable". That's fine, the next thing you should do is to identify the source of the problem and fix it in order to work predictable and how is should work instead of implementing such workarounds (I'm pretty sure it will also work unpredicatable)

Comment: Well, if you look at the source of the problem, you will see that it is not easy to fix. Imagine you are binding a grid to ObservableList<Person> and that list contains 10 persons.  If you bind Name property incorrectly (ex Namee), when running the app, you will receive 10 errors (for each person), that property is not found. However, if you receive only 2, and those two are for example for person 4 and person 5, then that is some strange problem. And now when I am thinking, it seems that it is happening when I am reloading new items (ex moving to next record), altough not 100% sure.

Comment: @Goran, maybe it would be easy to help you to fix the problem easily if you provide more accurate code?

Comment: I cannot provide you with the code, since the solution is very complex and big. I gave you the hearth of the problem. Can you tell me what can cause such behavior, because I haves spoken with many developers and they all told me its very strange problem and not easy to investigate. few hours ago I even read on telerik forums that their support suggest to avoid binding to ViewModel properties from DataTemplate. That all suggest that some issues could exist...

Comment: @Goran, so unfortunately I cannot help you without any more code. I doubt the code you provided is the heart of the problem as the problem cannot be found. I hope you'll resolve the problem quite fast. Good luck with that

Comment: @PiotrPtak I have issued support request to supplier, since probably it is the problem on their side. In the meantime, if you think you can contribute to answering this question (not the other question, related to binding faults), any idea is welcomed.